# Ajax doesn't trigger server action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am trying to trigger action via ajax but it doesn't call from some reason. Is my js code fine?

```
@Html.ActionLink("LIKE", "LikeComment", "Comments", new { id = 1985 }, new{@class = "likeButton"})

$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".likeButton").click(function () {            
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data("action-url"),
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    alert('ss');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: what do the elements with .likeButton look like?

Comment: <a class="likeButton" href="/Project.GUI/Comments/LikeComment/1985">LIKE</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".likeButton").click(function () {            
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("href"),
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    alert('ss');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Failed to load reource: http://localhost/Project.GUI/Comments/LikeComment/1985?_=1334575125907

Comment: this will not happen if you just use a "<a>" tag as follows, 
<a class="likeButton" href="/Comments/LikeComment/1985">LIKE</a>

Answer (score 1):

If your button code is
LIKE
then this part of ajax request is wrong:

**This is wrong**
url: $(this).data("action-url"),

**Do it like this**
url: $(this).attr("href"),